# GTM not working on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm developing native iOS app and using firebaseSDK to send data to GTM.
GTM started to log error on console and I can not see data on Google Analytics. I'm facing with error message below;

```
GoogleTagManager error: Error executing tag 1: TypeError: endsWith is not a function
```

What could be reason of the error? In what circumstances GTM logs this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that endsWith is not a function.

I presume you have a custom HTML tag or a javascript variable that [uses the endsWith function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) which is not yet supported by Safari Mobile.

Comment: It is a native iOS project, sorry for the confusion. I'm using FirebaseSDK to send data to GTM. I was not facing with the issue before.

Comment: Can you add this info to your question (that would allow me to delete the irrelevant answer) ?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in a recent change to GTM's container definition. We corrected the error today at approximately 3:30 PM PST. You should download the container file as part of your next build, but installed copies of your application(s) should retrieve an updated container within the next 12 hours.

Comment: Hi, I published a new version and downloaded new container but I'm still getting a error log.GoogleTagManager error: No parameter key specified in the data. GoogleTagManager error: Error executing tag 1: TypeError: cannot access property of null. How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused. The problem affected both iOS and Android apps.

A fix for the issue should be fully rolled out by now (making its way to apps via the 12 hour refresh interval). Please chime in if you are still encountering any problem.